# Custom Error Pages using ExecuteURL in .NET ASPX application not working (Redirects work fine)

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, webforms, web-config

This works and it redirects to yahoo.com as desired:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />      
  <error statusCode="401" path="http://www.yahoo.com" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
```

This doesn't, and the difference is that I'm specifying a page in my app rather than an external URL:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />      
  <error statusCode="401" path="/ErrorPages/401.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

The error I get on the screen is:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://localhost/app/MyPage.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

The status code of this error (seen via Firebug) is 403.  When I actually browse to /app/ErrorPages/401.aspx using a browser, I see the error page just fine.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, with the app deployed in IIS7 as a Virtual Directory through VS.

I looked at all the available docs. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a virtual directory you need to include the virtual directory path in the `path` attribute if it is not an absolute URI.

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically do that, in cases where the virtual directory can change?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no there isn't unfortunately. Using '~' causes IIS to throw an exception.

Comment: Cool. I've accepted your answer as that did solve the error I was receiving.